# Scala Cat library validation list group by Error code

Tags: scala, validation, functional-programming, scala-cats

I am new to Scala and functional programming.I did one validation using Scala cat library. But I can't able to group Invalid elements by error code.

```
case class Err(code: ErrorCode, elementName: String)
```

This is the output of invalid elements.

```
List(Invalid(NonEmptyList(Err(missingElement,Des), Err(InvalidElement,order), Err(InvalidElement,name), Err(InvalidElement,source))))
```

what I want is something like this

```
missingElement->List(Des)
InvalidElement->List(order,name,source)
```

Is there any functionality in  cat library itself for this? Or is there any workaround to get this?

Comment: Is the nesting of `List(Invalid(NonEmptyList))` intentional? Or would you just ideally want an `ValidatedNel[Err, ?]`? If it isn't intentional, could you please show the code generating this nesting?

Comment: Thanks for your time. The thing is I am validating collection of objects and collect all the invalid error codes.So it is like List(Invalid(NonEmptyList),Invalid(NonEmptyList),Valid(NonEmptyList)).Then i filter out all valid elements. From this List, i need to groupBy on error codes.

Comment: Understood. See the update on my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your full structure looks similar to this:

```
sealed trait ErrorCode
object ErrorCode {
  case object MissingElement extends ErrorCode
  case object InvalidElement extends ErrorCode
}

final case class Err(code: ErrorCode, elementName: String)
```

And we have a `ValidatedNel[Err, ?]`:

```
val res: ValidatedNel[Err, String] =
  Invalid(
    NonEmptyList(
      Err(ErrorCode.MissingElement, "Des"),
      List(
        Err(ErrorCode.InvalidElement, "order"),
        Err(ErrorCode.InvalidElement, "name"),
        Err(ErrorCode.InvalidElement, "source")
      )
    )
  )
```

Then what you'd need to do in order to group the list would be to use `groupBy` on the error side, using `leftMap`:

```
val groupedErrs: Validated[Map[ErrorCode, List[String]], String] =
  res.leftMap(
    _.toList
      .groupBy(_.code)
      .map { case (code, errs) => code -> errs.map(_.elementName) }
  )
```

Result:

```
Invalid(Map(InvalidElement -> List(order, name, source), MissingElement -> List(Des)))
```

If all this is inside a list of validations, `List[ValidatedNel[Err, ?]]`, then we just need an additional `map` operation to iterate the list:

```
val groupedErrs: List[Validated[Map[ErrorCode, List[String]], String]] = 
  res.map(
    _.leftMap(
      _.toList
        .groupBy(_.code)
        .map { case (code, errs) => code -> errs.map(_.elementName) }
    )
  )
```

Result:

```
List(Invalid(Map(InvalidElement -> List(order, name, source), MissingElement -> List(Des))))
```